# Faster way to change dataframe's row value based upon condition

Tags: python, pandas, performance, dataframe

I have a *large dataframe* containing ***millions of records***,

---

[image: data set]

---

*Lists that I am using in my code are*,

```
image_jpg= ['image/jpeg','image/jpg','image/pjpeg']
image_png = ['image/png','image/x-png','application/png']
image_gif = ['image/gif']
```

---

I want to *make* a new column named `name` such that, for example:

*Index 0* has `content_type` value `image/jpeg` that is in the *list* `image_jpg`, so, `name` column *get value* of `5efc61356f85e500694bcbbbbb3ee4c2.jpg` ( `sys_id` *column* + `.jpg`)

---

*Right now I am achieving this via*:

```
file_name = []
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    if row['content_type'] in image_jpg:
        file_name.append(str(row['sys_id'])+'.jpg')
    elif row['content_type'] in image_png:
        file_name.append(str(row['sys_id'])+'.png')
    elif row['content_type'] in image_png:
        file_name.append(str(row['sys_id'])+'.gif')
    else:
        file_name.append(str(row['sys_id']))

df['name'] =  file_name
```

*Output*:

[image: output]

Problem is, it takes quite a long time, since dataframe is quite large.

*Is there a faster way to accomplish this task ?*

Answer (score 1):

Use a dictionary and *column-wise* operations:

```
d = {'image_jpg': ['image/jpeg','image/jpg','image/pjpeg'],
     'image_png': ['image/png','image/x-png','application/png'],
     'image_gif': ['image/gif']}

d_rev = {w: k for k, v in d.items() for w in v}

for k, v in d_rev.items():
    mask = df['content_type'].str.contains(v, regex=False)
    df.loc[mask, 'name'] = df.loc[mask, 'sys_id'] + '.' + k.split('/')[-1]
```

Or, if equality is required:

```
for k, v in d_rev.items():
    mask = df['content_type'].eq(v)
    df.loc[mask, 'name'] = df.loc[mask, 'sys_id'] + '.' + k.split('/')[-1]
```

For the equality case, [@AntonvBR's `pd.Series.map` solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52774626/9209546) is better.

**Explanation**

`d_rev` maps each list value to a key:-

```
print(d_rev)

{'application/png': 'image_png', 'image/gif': 'image_gif',
 'image/jpeg': 'image_jpg', 'image/jpg': 'image_jpg',
 'image/pjpeg': 'image_jpg', 'image/png': 'image_png',
 'image/x-png': 'image_png'}
```

Given there are very few categories and a large number of rows, it is more efficient to iterate the dictionary and use optimized column-wise operations. Remember `iterrows` is just a slow row-wise loop, it will always be inefficient for a large number of rows.

Answer (score 1):

I would restructure your lists to a dictionary and use map:

`df['name'] = df['id'] + df['content_type'].map(d).fillna('')`

thanks to @jezrael we should also add a fillna('') to handle errors.

---

Meaning you should replace your list by something like this:

```
d = {
    'application/png': '.png',
    'image/gif': '.gif',
    'image/jpeg': '.jpg',
    'image/jpg': '.jpg',
    'image/pjpeg': '.jpg',
    'image/png': '.png',
    'image/x-png': '.png',
}
```

---

Full example:

```
import pandas as pd

d = {
    'application/png': '.png',
    'image/gif': '.gif',
    'image/jpeg': '.jpg',
    'image/jpg': '.jpg',
    'image/pjpeg': '.jpg',
    'image/png': '.png',
    'image/x-png': '.png',
}

# some random data
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'id': ['1232131iujajga','21hi3hk123h21', '1231231231'],
    'content_type': ['image/gif', 'image/jpg', '']
})

df['name'] = df['id'] + df['content_type'].map(d).fillna('')
print(df)
```

Returns:

```
 content_type              id                name
0    image/gif  1232131iujajga  1232131iujajga.gif
1    image/jpg   21hi3hk123h21   21hi3hk123h21.jpg
2                   1231231231          1231231231
```

Comment: Or `df['name'] = df['id'] + df['content_type'].map(d).fillna('')` for convert not matched values to empty string

Comment: Could you be kind enough to show how can I restructure my lists to a dictionary via code ?

Comment: @MohammadZainAbbas I just did (it is the d dictionary, a map between what you have and what you want) 
Or do you get the lists from somewhere else?